# How to prove that for all odd $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ can be displayed as the difference of two square numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification, induction, natural-numbers

I need guidance / correction for my proof. It's a little bit longer, but we really have to consider everything. If you find some issues / mistakes or have suggestions to improve it, please let me know! It helps alot!

Claim: All odd $$ n  \in \mathbb{N} $$ can be displayed by the difference of two square numbers.

$$ k \in \mathbb{N0}$$ is a "square number" if there exists an
$$ m \in \mathbb{N0}$$ that is $$m^2 = k $$

My proof (please critique if you think something is missing)

Every $$n \in \mathbb{N}$$ can be displayed by $$(2k-1) = n^2$$

Proof by induction:

For n=1:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{1} = (2*1-1)=1 = 1^2 $$

Proof for n+1:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{n+1} = (2n-1) = (n+1)^2 $$

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{n+1} = (2n-1) + (2(n+1)-1) = (n+1)^2 $$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{n+1} = (n^2) + (2(n+1)-1) = (n+1)^2 $$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{n+1} = (n^2) + (2n+1) = (n+1)^2 $$

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{n+1} = (n^2 + 2n+1) = (n+1)^2 $$
End of induction proof.

From (n+1)^2 we can see the following:

$$ (n+1)^2 = (n^2+2n+1) $$$$ (n+1)^2 - n^2 = (2n+1) $$

Therefor, every $$ n \in \mathbb{N} $$ can be displayed by the difference of two square numbers with
$$ (n+1)^2 - n^2 $$.
Any critiques? The prof is really nitpicky and i would really appreciate some input to make the proof "bulletproof".

Comment: Why don't you just say that $2n-1=n^2-(n-1)^2$?

Comment: The professor is as mentioned really nitpicking and it needs to be really carefully written. If you have any suggestions how to do it in a different way while taking that into consideration, let me know

Comment: I think his point is you don't need to introduce another symbol k. If you take a look at some examples ($1 = 1^2 - (1-1)^2, 3 = 2^2 - (2-1)^2, 5 = 3^2 - (3-1)^2, ...$ youll see that $2n-1 = n^2 - (n-1)^2$ is exactly what you want to do induction on to see its true

Comment: @UpCup the k symbol is just mentioned as shown in the task. I don't think we really have to use it? Ive changed the one part where i had accidentaly the (2k-1) instead of (2n-1). So do you think its good how i did show it by induction?

Comment: It looks like your trying to show that $2n-1 = n^2$ which is not true. What you want to show is that an odd number $2n-1$ is equal to a difference of squares $n^2 - (n-1)^2$. But first convince yourself its true. Take some square and the square before it, for example 16 and 9. Their difference is 7. Take the next pair, 25 and 16. Difference is 9. Then the next, 36 and 25. Difference is 11. From here it should be obvious that you can get all the odds by by subtracting a specific square and the previous square. Specifically $2n-1 = n^2 - (n-1)^2$

Comment: @UpCup what makes you think 2n-1 = n^2 is not true if i may ask? I know that you can display each odd number via (n+1)^2 - n^2. But like i said, i can't just write it down like that. There needs to be a proof and that's why used induction for it. If you think there is a proper way to do that, write it down as an answer, would really appreciate it as i really would like to see another approach to this problem. Would really help.

Comment: @JohnGam: $2n-1=n^2$ if and only if $n^2-2n+1=0$, i.e., if and only if $(n-1)^2=0$, and this is the case precisely when $n=1$; for any other value of $n$ it is false.

Comment: If $n=3$ then $2n-1 = 7$ and $n^2 = 9$. And I think your confusing yourself or maybe unclear about what induction is trying to accomplish. You make a claim, your not sure if its true or not, but you think it may be true. In this case, you think that you every odd can be written as a difference of squares, $2n-1 = n^2 - (n-1)^2$. Now induction is saying, okay lets find a case where it works, and if it works for one, then we it will work for next. So we assume it works for $n=1$ which is true as $1=1$, now assume its true for $n=k$ st $2k-1 = k^2 - (k-1)^2$. Now prove its true for $k+1$

Comment: @UpCup but for n=3 2n-1 is indeed 9, as well as n^2 it is 9, don't forget the sigma sign.

Comment: You not being asked to prove that  $\Sigma$ odds $= n^2$, your proving that an odd can be written as the difference of two squares. Now I'm not saying that they aren't essentially the same thing because $2n-1 = n^2 - (n-1)^2 \Leftrightarrow n^2 = 2n-1 + (n-1)^2$.

Comment: @UpCup okay, i will reconsider the induction then. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

No induction is needed. Let $n$ be an odd positive integer; then there is a non-negative integer $k$ such that $n=2k+1$. And

$$n=2k+1=(k^2+2k+1)-k^2=(k+1)^2-k^2\,,$$

so $n$ is the difference of two squares — indeed, of two consecutive squares.

Comment: I see, i mean i came up with a simliar solution in the first place. I mean i could also solve it visually with some squares, but i used the induction to be on the safe side. I saw that you also commented that "2−1=2 if and only if 2−2+1=0" but how? 2n-1=n^2 is always true, since for example n = 2 for 2n-1 = 4 and n^2 = 4. and so on, since there is a sigma sign, you have to take the sum, or am i wrong?

Comment: @JohnGam: Using induction is not being on the safe side: it’s imply doing a great deal of unnecessary work and overcomplicating the argument, thereby (a) giving you more opportunities to go astray and (b) making life harder for the reader. When $n=2$, $2n-1=3$, not $4$.

Comment: Okay, i will rethink my decision. Quick Discussion for the induction: 2n-1 is not 3 but 4. 1+3 = 4, as well as n^2 for n=2. You can't ignore the sigma notification, it is a sum? Why do some of you say it is 3? You can't just ignore the previous element in a sum?

Comment: @JohnGam: We’re simply reading what you write. When you write *what makes you think 2n-1 = n^2 is not true if i may ask?*, you are implying that you think that $2n-1=n^2$, and this is in general not true. There is no summation sign there.

Comment: If you would simply read what i write, you would see that i mentioned just under your answer in my first comment, the sigma sign and see it in the original question, it was you who claimed simply 2n-1 != n^2 without reference. Just wanted to clear that up as it got me confused, no need to blame it on me. Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: @JohnGam: You mentioned a summation sign, but none is present in your comment, and you wrote something — *2n-1=n^2 is always true* — that is simply false. I am not being pedantic or picky: these are fundamental failures to communicate your meaning. And it is not true that I ‘claimed simply 2n-1 != n^2 without reference’: I **proved** that assertion in my comment under the question.